# Creating a dynamic div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display a div tag in HTML which will only show when the user views the page in Print Preview. The div tag appears in print preview however it appears on top of the content. I need the div tag to appear at the end of every page so on every printed page and not on top of the content, In other words it needs to be dynamic otherwise it just prints on top of other content - see css below

```
<style>
@media screen {
    div.divFooter {
        display: none;
    }
}
@media print {
    div.divFooter {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
    }
}

* {
 margin: 0;
}

</style>
```

HTML

```
<div class="print">
 <div class="divFooter">
<p class="boxes">A</p>
 <p class="boxes">B</p>
 <center><p class="C</center>
  </div>
  </div>
```

The print class basically ensures that the div is hidden and only visible in print preview. Is there a way I can amend CSS to ensure that the sticky footer is not displayed on top of content but in fact its dynamic and appears in its own space?

Comment: Can you position the footer where you actually want it? Then you would just need `position: static;`

Comment: but then it does not appear on all pages just appears on first page

Comment: Will you always be printing on the same media (8 1/2x11 or A4, for example)?